# Needed code to handle Windows Security alert user id and password

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate Microsoft Reflection Workspace. I have successfully triggered the application but I am getting Windows alert to enter user id and password.

Could you please help me on the code to handle user id and password.

Comment: Please include the code you are trying to use in your question, and explain the specific problem you are having with it. Namely, which specific error on which specific line.

Comment: You needed the code and have it?

Comment: This has what to do with mainframes? Are you trying to do something from a mainframe session, to a mainframe session or are you talking about RACF or some other mainframe security software?

Comment: Hi  @braX thanks for the response. Problem : While opening an application. I am getting Windows Security dilagoue Box to enter the credentials.  I need VBA code and reference library to enter the credentials. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the below code is not workingCreating an script object
Set oWSH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


'Activating alert screen    
oWSH.AppActivate ("Windows Security")


'Passing the value UserName/UserID
oWSH.SendKeys "USERNAME<username><username>"     'ensure to complete the username with apropriate domain e.g., abc/A123456

'Changing the focus to password textbox
oWSH.SendKeys "{TAB}"


'Passing the value password
oWSH.SendKeys "PASSWORD"
    
'Clicking enter to complete the screen
'oWSH.SendKeys "{ENTER}"


'Releasing the script object
Set oWSH = Nothing

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Please describe the error with relevant error messages (in full).

Comment: Send keys are not working